# Accessing input value from stateless child component in parent through refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm creating a program to track store inventory.  I have an array of item names (strings) that I map through to generate a component that renders a heading for each item along with a corresponding input field:

```
function Inventory(props){
    let items = ['milk', 'bread', 'butter'],
        itemInput = items.map((value,index) => {
      return(
        <div key={index}>
          <h3>{value}</h3>
          <input type={'text'} />
        </div>
      )
    })

    return(
      <div>
        {itemInput}
      </div>
    )
};
```

[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCz5l.png)

How can I access both the input value as well as well as its corresponding heading? For example, if I type `5` within the input for `milk`, I want to be able to access both `5` and `milk`.

I've tried using `refs` (which winds up referencing only the last array item), `event` and `this` to no avail.  Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use the onChange handler for this:

```
<input type="text" onChange={e => this.setState({ [value]: e.target.value })} />
```

The state now will look something like this:

```
{
  milk: 5,
  bread: 2,
  butter: 10
}
```

Comment: @lightspeed, This solution works for a functional component????????????????

Comment: After converting this to a stateful component, it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `functional` component which doesn't have a `state` or  `refs`. You have two options, Either set the value as props passed down from the parent or make it a `stateful` component.

`Stateless` components must be dumb component used specifically for rendering and all logic must reside in the `stateful parent component`.

According to the **[docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)**

> You may not use the ref attribute on functional components because
>   they don't have instances.You should convert the component to a class
>   if you need a ref to it, just like you do when you need lifecycle
>   methods or state

In first case

```
    function Inventory(props){
      let items = ['milk', 'bread', 'butter'],
      itemInput = items.map((val,index) => {
      return(
        <div key={index}>
          <h3>{val}</h3>
          <input type={'text'} value={props.childInput[val] || '' } onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(e, val)}/>
        </div>
      )
    })

    return(
      <div>
        {itemInput}
      </div>
    )
};
```

And then the parent will have the logic like

```
 <Inventory handleChange={this.handleChange} childInput={this.state.childInputVal}/>


 handleChange = (e, key) => {
      var childInputVal = {...this.state.childInputVal}
      childInputVal[key] = e.target.value
      this.setState({childInputVal})
 }

 state = {
      childInputVal: {}

 }
```

The other option is to make this component itself a stateful component

```
class Inventory extends React.Component {
    state= {
        inputValues: {}  
     }
   handleChange = (e, val) => {
        handleChange = (e, key) => {
         var childInputVal = {...this.state.inputValues}
         inputValues[key] = e.target.value
         this.setState({inputValues})

   }
   render() {
      let items = ['milk', 'bread', 'butter'],
      itemInput = items.map((val,index) => {
      return(
        <div key={index}>
          <h3>{val}</h3>
          <input type={'text'} value={this.state.inputValues[val] || '' } onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, val)}/>
        </div>
      )

    }
    return(
      <div>
        {itemInput}
      </div>
    )
}
```