# React component can't take ref

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm trying to give the components I render on an array.map a reference so later on I can call some of the functions inside those components.

There would be 3 instances of the same component, and I'm getting this error when give them a ref:

```
Uncaught Error: Stateless function components cannot have refs.
```

Here, the render method of the parent component that is trying to render those 3 children components:

```
render() {
const { strings } = this.props;

const ElementsContainer = ({elements}) => (
  <div className="containerSection">
    {elements.map( (element, i) => {
      return(<div key={"container"+i} className="camaraLentaContainer" id={"camaraLentaContainer" + i}>

        <CamaraLenta ref={"camaraLenta"+i} index={i} images={element.camaraLenta.images}/>

      </div>)
      })
    }
  </div>
)

return (
  <div className="home" >

    <ElementsContainer elements={strings.elements} />

  </div>
);
```

}

Here, the CamaraLenta (child) component, very simplified so we can see..

```
import ...;

export default class CamaraLenta extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
  };

  static contextTypes = {
    baseUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    project: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        slideIndex: 0,
        loading: false,
        imagesTotalDataSrc: [],
        imagesTotalDataLoaded: 0,
        timeoutSlider: null
    };

    this.handleSliderClick = this.handleSliderClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }

    //Touch/Click slider, we kill timeout
    handleSliderClick() {
        clearTimeout(this.state.timeoutSlider);
    }

    registerEvents(){
        $("html, body").on("scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove", function(){
        $("html, body").stop().unbind('scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup'); 
      });
    }

  render() {
    const {index} = this.props;

    return (
      <div>

        <div className="slidesContainer"> 
            <canvas id={"stage" + index}>
                Tu navegador no soporta canvas
            </canvas>
            <div className="slider" id={"slider" + index} onClick={this.handleSliderClick}></div>

            <Loading visible={this.state.loading}/>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}`
```

My versions:

```
"react": "^15.5.4",
"react-redux": "^5.0.5",
"redux": "^3.7.0",
```

Comment: If I delete the reference to the CamaraLenta components I'm rendering, the error goes away, but I cannot use them later on from the parent, of course...

Comment: That is because stateless function don't have access to this  keyword or refs

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44473449/react-multiple-input-reference/44473720#44473720

Comment: I don't understand. Both components have state, so they are not stateless.

Comment: Your overall component may be but your ElementsContainer  is a a stateless component

Comment: you are right sir. I finally fixed it. Check out the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Stateless component don't work with refs, if you really want to uncapsulate your component using the findDOMNode, convert your component to a class based component or downgrade your react to any version before 0.14 (**not recommended**).

More info in this page, the discussion about why they removed this feature from stateless components https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4936

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yuri. The thing here is that my component is stateful, as you can see above. I declared it in the constructor using this.state = {...}. Is it not anymore a valid way to declare the state? Maybe React 15+ doesn't realize that this component does have a state? thanks

Comment: Ohhh, you mean the parent component? maybe there is no state, I'm not sure now as I don't have the code with me... will check tomorrow first thing!

Comment: I don't understand. Both components have state, so they are not stateless.

Answer (score 1):

Alright. I was getting it wrong as some people suggested on the answers. The stateless component/function is ElementsContainer, which I declared right there on my render function.

Finally, I changed the way I declare my reference to this:

```
ref={ el => this.camerasRefs.push(el) }
```

And, in my main component constructor, I declared that variable like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      triggeredSections: []
    };

    this.camerasRefs = [];

  }
```

So I can finally access my CamaraLenta components using this array.

```
  handleRepeat(index) {
    this.camerasRefs[index].handleRepeat();
  }
```

Thank you for all your help and understanding!